# Changing player heads size that are on the ground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The Minecraft YouTuber, Wisp, has a texture pack and plays Hypixel UHC. When he kills people, they drop player heads, but they're enlarged when on the ground. How does he do it? Can you tell me how to edit a PLAYER HEAD size on the ground?

Comment: Probably a resource pack. You should ask him and/or the server owner.

Answer (score 1):

Get your resource pack and go into **resource pack/assets/minecraft/models/item**. Now create a file called "player_head.json" (make sure it is .json and not .txt) and paste this in:

```
{
    "parent": "item/template_skull",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 75, 125, 0 ],
            "translation": [ -1, 3, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.8, 0.8, 0.8 ]
        },
        "ground": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 3, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ]
        },
        "fixed": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 1, 1, 1 ]
        },
        "firstperson_righthand": {
            "rotation": [ 0, 135, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 3, 1, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.8, 0.8, 0.8 ]
        },
        "gui": {
            "rotation": [ 35, -145, 0 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 1.25, 0 ],
            "scale": [ 0.8, 0.8, 0.8 ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now you see where is says scale in the ground section? the default is 0.5 but you can increase it to increase the head size. I suggest using 1.